# Simplify $B=\sqrt{x^2} - x$

Tags: radicals

I have to simplify the following expression:

$B=\sqrt{x^2} - x$

The only thing that I can do is:

$\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$, thus $B=|x|-x$. 
Is that enough?

Comment: ... or $\max\{-2x,0\}$ - depending on what is perseived as simpler

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, I did not understand this. How did you get it $-\max\{-2x,0\}$?

Comment: +1 for not writing "it's obviously $0$" and skipping to the next question.

Answer (score 6):

$B=0$ if $x\geq0$ and $B=-2x$ if $x\leq 0$

Comment: How can I describe this? Is it enough to write it after the expression I got? Should I add justification?

Comment: yes of course. You can just add it after what you did

Comment: Nice answer. Maybe you want to use large braces like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54108/curly-braces-and-nested-arrays

Comment: yes it is very useful. Thanks